# background image can't move up with content

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I am developing a phone application using jQuery Mobile. I set background image to following DIV: (code copy from developer tools after page rendered)

```
<div data-role="page" id="create_member" data-dom-cache="true" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-page-theme-a ui-page-active" style="height: 568px;"><div data-role="content" class="ui-content" role="main">
```

CSS:

```
#create_member {
  background-image: url("../images/common/bg.png");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: top;
 }
```

bg.png  is a 640x1136 background and fit iphone5 size.

There is a banner beneath it:

```
  <div class="banner">

        <div class="bannerbg"><img src="skin/images/red_banner.png" \=""> </div>

   </div>
```

CSS:

```
#create_member .banner {
margin-top: 34%;
}

.bannerbg {
 border-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
background: #ffe6b8;
}

.banner img {
width: 97%;
margin-top: 5px;
}
```

However, when I try to scroll the page down, I found this background is fixed, banner can be moved up but not this background.

How could I make the banner sits together with the background and when scroll up the device, they move together?

Comment: Has a side note, you don't need *-moz-* for `border radius`, unless you want to support **Firefox 3.6**. *-webkit-* is also not required anymore, but you could leave it there for backward compatibility for **Safari 4.0** and **Android browser 2.1**.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to use the `background-image` **CSS** *attribute* to pick an image and then have some sort of banner attached to it. See this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bh8ac/1) to confirm if this is the behaviour you were looking for. What you were missing is having your parent element with `relative` *positioning* and your child element with `absolute` *positioning*.

**Why we use the absolute positioning for the banner**

> *In the absolute positioning model, a box is explicitly offset with respect to its containing block* - [w3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#absolute-positioning)

**Why we need relative positioning for the containing block**

> *A relatively positioned box establishes a new containing block for absolutely positioned descendants.* - [w3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#relative-positioning)

If you didn't have the `relative` *positioning*, your banner would instead follow the `body` has a *containing block*. Following those two *postioning* properties, the trick was to use `bottom`, `left` and `right` at `0px` to have it stick as a banner at the bottom of the *parent*, while still scaling in height with it's own content.

```
.banner {
    position:relative;
}

.bannerbg {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
}
```

Not sure if it's what you were looking for. Let me know so I can adjust my answer if I didn't get it! :-)

Comment: Hi @Kad, thank you for your quick response and give an example. The issue I met is slightly different. I guess it's something with the data-role="page" in JQM, maybe i can't set background of that div.

Comment: hi, i've figured out... in my css, there is an attribute: .ui-page-active {
display: block;
overflow: visible;
/* overflow-x: hidden; */   the overflow-x: hidden makes the bg fixed.

Comment: but i am not sure what side-effect will occur if i removed it